# Transform the $a_n$ to 'secondary degree 'equation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, linear-transformations

I am refering to this article https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Recurrence-Relations, in the section "Linear", we see the  $a_{n}=2a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2}$
and tranform into this $x^{2}-2x-5=0$.

1. How would it be this  $a_{n+1}+a_{n}-2^{n}=0$? I can't understand I can't beleive it is  $x^{2}+x-2=0$ because it has $2^{n}$.
2. or if it was like $2^{n-1}$ or $2^{n+1}$. What happen in this cases?

I didn't find something similar how to transform this.

Comment: The approach with the roots of the polynomial of course only works in special cases, for example homogenous linear recurrences. For more complicated recurrences, you need additional tools.

Comment: What additional tools? You know how to do 1. Or2.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to convert like this.
Let's prove by induction on $n$ that if
$$
a_{n+1}=2^n-a_n,\qquad\quad (1)
$$ then
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+2a_{n-1}.\qquad(2)
$$
Let us assume that $a_0=t$. Then from $(1)$ we get $a_1=1-t$, $a_2=1+t$. From $(2)$ we get $a_2=1-t+2t=1+t$. This is the basis of induction. Let $n\geq3$. Since by convention $a_{n+1}=2^n-a_n$ and $2^{n-1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$, then
$$
a_{n+1}=2^n-a_n=2(a_n+a_{n-a})-a_n=a_n+2a_{n-1}.\qquad(3)
$$
With this we have proved that the formulas $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent,
but $(2)$ is linear.

Comment: Questions. How you get the (2)? Second question, you prove that the (2) is linear ok. As I get you must do the second relationship this $x^{2}$ + 2x-1

Comment: How I got $(2)$ is stated in $(3)$. Next you have to solve the quadratic equation $x^2-x-2=0$. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are its roots, then $a_n=c_1x_1^n+c_2x_2^n$, where $c_1, c_2$ are computed if $a_0$ and $a_1$ are known. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) for details.

Comment: Ok got it. I confused How you get the $x^{2}$ - x - 2. The other parts ok I understand

Comment: If $a_{n+1}=pa_n+qa_{n-1}$, then $x^2=px+q$.

Comment: thank you for your help